# Can I merge Syntax coloring and Folding? OR Projection colored from master document info

Tags: syntax-highlighting, eclipse-rcp, projection, text-coloring

Example. I have an XML document:

```
<document>
<region type="type1">text of region1
</region>
some simple text
<region type="type2">text of region2
</region>
```

And I want it to be presented as

**text of region1**
some simple text
*text of region2*

The basic Eclipse coloring works independent from folding, as I know. But I need text to be colored depending on the xml info. Or maybe I need something other, than folding? It's probably easier to just manipulate StyledText, but I need other Eclipse Editor functions to continue working.

=========
**upd:** Still no suggestions? Is it at least possible?
I've looked at projection, but... does text attributes directly accessible from this branch of editor?
**upd**: Maybe at least some thoughts/articles about custom projections?

Comment: I mean, I need "projection with coloring"

Comment: more precisely, "projection colored from master document info"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implementet it via document listener service, ProjectionDocument.removeMasterDocumentRange and ProjectionDocument.getDocumentInformationMapping(). Coloring by SourceViewer.getTextWidget().setStyleRange(). There is a little problem if PresentationReconciler will be added, but since I know it, its safe.