# Eclipse RCP - Internals of projection (folding) service

Tags: eclipse-rcp, projection, folding

I need to make custom text folding as described here: [Can I merge Syntax coloring and Folding? OR Projection colored from master document info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017375/can-i-merge-syntax-coloring-and-folding-or-projection-colored-from-master-docume)
I'm digging through code, but its very perplexed... and I cant get access to some classes.
I still haven't found what class decides what to show when ProjectionAnnotation collapsed
I need some info on how folding/projection is implemented, but haven't found any articles.
Please if somebody familiar with Eclipse projection, or knows any articles, help!

The basic goals:
1) make ProjectionAnnotations to show text enclosed in xml tags, instead of first line
2) make ProjectionAnnotations unexpandable(permanently collapsed)
3) remove collapse/expand button (I think I know how to do it, but this decorative and have less priority)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the excellent [Eclipse corner article](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Folding-in-Eclipse-Text-Editors/folding.html), you could also try looking at how [Spring IDE](http://springide.org/blog/tag/mylyn) implemented it (check out their source code from [here](http://springide.org/project/wiki/SpringideRepository)).

Comment: that article was first I've read about this problem. I've managed to do my text folding, but still have some troubles with model and presentation, that need more preciese understandig how it works inside.
as for Spring IDE... from what I see on screenshots, its standard folding. It's not fit, because those annotations take full line of text for theyselves, but I need many foldings per line.
thanks for the try whatever.

Comment: How would you represent multiple foldings on a single line?

Comment: i don't need them to be openable, so they hardly folded by document listener